# Zend Framework - Integration Mad File Manager in TinyMCE

Tags: zend-framework, tinymce, integration

I have a problem with Mad File Manager integration in TinyMCE.
I think the problem is in this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MadFileBrowser(field_name, url, type, win) {
      tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
          file : "mfm.php?field=" + field_name + "&url=" + url + "",
      }, {
          window : win,
          input : field_name
      });
      return false;
    }
</script>
```

in

```
file : "mfm.php?field=" + field_name + "&url=" + url + ""
```

because Zend Framework returns exception: **Message: Invalid controller specified (mfm.php)**

```
Request Parameters:
array (
  'controller' => 'mfm.php',
  'action' => 'index',
  'module' => 'default',
  'field' => 'src',
  'url' => '',
)
```

Comment: what is your controller name? is it mfm.phpController?

Comment: I don't have any controller for that. mfm.php is really PHP file from the author of Mad File Manager.

Comment: You must have a controller, for more information you can see my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the controller is named MfmController.php you should be doing:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MadFileBrowser(field_name, url, type, win) {
      tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
          file : "/mfm?field=" + field_name + "&url=" + url + "",
      }, {
          window : win,
          input : field_name
      });
      return false;
    }
</script>
```

In zend framework you never invoke a .php directly. Every requests passes thru index.php and is routed to the right controller by Zend_Route.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Zend Framework all of your request passes through front controller of your application, that is `index.php`. `index.php` parses your request url of this format (controllername/actionname?param) and forwards the request of your specified controller's specified action(this is the default behavior). For that case you should have a controller named `controllernameController` and an action of that controller named `actionnameAction`. That is why

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function MadFileBrowser(field_name, url, type, win) {
  tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
      file : "mfm.php?field=" + field_name + "&url=" + url + "",
  }, {
      window : win,
      input : field_name
  });
  return false;
}
</script>
```

should be

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function MadFileBrowser(field_name, url, type, win) {
  tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
      file : "mfm?field=" + field_name + "&url=" + url + "",
  }, {
      window : win,
      input : field_name
  });
  return false;
}
</script>
```

And you should have a controller named `mfmController` with `indexAction` method to handle your request (if no action is mentioned, indexAction is executed by default).

Cheers and happy coding!